# opencart the length of "address"

Tags: opencart, checkout, opencart-3

The opencart 3.0.2.0 system will limit users from entering their address in checkout more than 128 characters, is there any possible ways to modify this?
I do have some customers complain to me about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `oc_address` CHANGE `address_1` `address_1` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Note: if your database prefix is not `oc_`, edit above query and use your actual database prefix.
This query will change the `address_1` limit from 128 to 256.